# Common Keyword/ Substring in a List of Company Name

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, string-search

Suppose I have several lists of company names which are all operating in the steel and property industries, respectively. How to guess a company industry based on the current list?
example:

```
steel=['Steelson Inc', 'First Steel Inc', 'North Steel Inc', 'Hard Hammer Inc', 'Mythril Forge Ltd'] 
propert=['New Land Inc', ' Green Meadow Inc', ' Golden Land Inc', 'City Lander Inc'] 

name='World Steel Inc'
print(find_industry(name))
```

Above code should print 'steel'.

I do not know how to best approach this problem, from Machine Learning or traditional string search methods. Please note that this problem might be different from longest common substring problem, because the 'key string' (or in above example 'steel') does not necessarily have to be appeared in all of the string in the list. Any help is appreciated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: Your question is too broad and asking for recommendations. If you try the (partial) string matching approach, and write some code, you can ask here how to get it to work (better). If you try the machine learning approach, the same applies. I will note that there's going to be a few catches with the string approach, since the 'World' part might be common in property company names, while the 'Steel' part would be common in steel company names, with the 'Inc' not helping at all, so a purely string-based solution may give you a very weak result.

Comment: I only have general idea with machine learning. Such as, to split each company name into every possible substrings, make those substring as features, and apply Random Forest on it.  But I am afraid I am new in machine learning. So if anyone know whether that is indeed possible, I will start dig deeper and post some codes.